# Jquery скрывать / показывать блоки при клике на самих себя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет

В коде реализовано скрыть / открыть при нажатии на другие блоки
Сейчас нужно также добавить функцию, чтобы при нажатии на открытый блок он скрывался. Тоесть при повтороном нажатии на открытый блок он прятался
Не могу понять как это сделать, кто что подскажет ?

```js
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как-то так:

```js
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle();
              jQuery('.targetDiv').not('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).hide();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Comment: _"чтобы при нажатии на открытый блок он скрывался"_ ©

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте этот обработчик клика и к `.targetDiv`. В самом обработчике определите, что именно было нажато, ссылка или див. Определите переменную - блок который надо скрыть/показать. После чего используйте `toggle()` чтобы скрыть или показать его, а все соседние дивы скройте.

атрибут `target` заменил на `data-target`. В целом туда проще сразу вписать `id` блока, а не его номер.

*зы: повторный клик по ссылке скрывает блок, не знаю нужно ли вам такое поведение*

```js
$('.showSingle, .targetDiv').click(function(){

    var $td = $(this);  // по умолчанию считаем что кликнули в блок

    // но если это была ссылка, то ищем блок
    if($(this).hasClass('showSingle')){
        var target =  $(this).data('target');
        $td = $("#div" + target);
    }

    $td.toggle()
       .siblings().hide();    
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div class="targets">
  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
  <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
</div>
```

Поскольку вероятно я не так понял ваш вопрос, и имеется  виду скрытие по повторному нажатию на ссылку, то конечно все гораздо проще

```js
$('.showSingle').click(function(){
    var target =  $(this).data('target');    
    $("#div" + target).toggle()
                      .siblings().hide();    
});
```

```css
.targetDiv {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a  class="showSingle" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div class="targets">
  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
  <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ох, Вы наворотили... там всего-то надо - поменять show() на toggle() и отменить через .not сокрытие '#div'+$(this).attr('target')

Comment: @humster_spb вы вопрос прочитайте, скрывать надо по клику на сам блок, чего в вашем ответе нет.

Comment: так и Вы читайте внимательно - "В коде реализовано скрыть / открыть при нажатии на другие блоки". Где там НАЖАТИЕ НА БЛОКИ? Нажатие на ссылки идёт. Просто автор вопроса неточно сформулировал. Так что "нажатие на блоки" не при чём.

Comment: @humster_spb да, действительно.

Comment: @humster_spb дополнил ответ

Comment: ну да, расширенный функционал :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.buttons').on('click', '.showSingle', function(e) {
    $('#' + this.getAttribute('target')).toggle();
  });
  
  $('.targetDiv').on('click', function(e) { $(this).hide() });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
<a  class="showSingle" target="div1">Div 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="div2">Div 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="div3">Div 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="div4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" hidden>Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" hidden>Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" hidden>Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" hidden>Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```